# How can i set the following cookie to be valid for all subdomains?

Tags: javascript, cookies, subdomain

Sorry for the question but i'm pretty new to javascript.

I'm using this javascript to set a cookie for my domain:

`document.cookie = 'mycookie=session-15773; expires=Tue, 23 June 2029 22:47:11 UTC; path=/'`

I'd like this cookie to be set for every *.example.com - How can i edit my javascript code to also include the command to set the cookies to every subdomains?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.cookie = "cookieVal=2;path=/;domain=bar.com";
```

This cookie should now be accessible to all sub domains of bar.com like foo.bar.com